# Hard deleting accidental answers within a timeframe to avoid bounty penalties

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, bounty, deleted-answers

On Friday I posted this question on StackOverflow:

[Retry on 408 Timeout from Azure Table Storage service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661635/retry-on-408-timeout-from-azure-table-storage-service)

The question has attracted a few comments but, so far, no answers. Soon after I posted the question, user [@rabtFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1536132/rabtft) left a comment to ask for more information. As I was on the train at the time, I made use of the StackOverflow app to reply to rabtFT. Unfortunately, I must have pressed "Add Answer" instead of "Reply" and my comment showed up as an answer.

I tried to delete the answer immediately but to my consternation there is no way to delete an answer from the StackOverflow app. So I was forced to sign in on my mobile browser to delete the answer that way. I posted and deleted this answer within minutes, if not seconds, yet a clearly "non-answer" is now permanently attached to this question (albiet deleted).

This was annoying, but I could live with it until I tried to post a bounty on this question today. It turns out the minimum bounty I can award is now 100, not 50, because according to [the bounty mechanics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

*(Yes, I could just post a 100 bounty but I'm being a little stingy with my rep because I'm just on the cusp of the 2000 mark.)*

From this experience I have four questions / observations / suggestions:

- Does the app need a delete answer button?
- Could more of a differentiation between the answer and comment buttons could be useful because it was a very easy mistake to make?
- Perhaps answers that have attracted no attention and/or are deleted within minutes of posting should be hard-deleted. Does it make sense to store and display obvious junk?
- Could deleted answers not count towards the "self promotion" rule on bounties?

It might be trivial, but the bounty rule I have come up against is perhaps just one example where a accidental, deleted answer could cause side effects on the site mechanics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- > *"Does the app need a delete answer button?"*

That button already exists:

> [image]

- > *"Could more of a differentiation between the answer and comment buttons could be useful because it was a very easy mistake to make?"*

I don't think that's necessary. There's quite a big difference between the two buttons, already:

> [image]

- > *"Perhaps answers that have attracted no attention and/or are deleted within minutes of posting should be hard-deleted. Does it make sense to store and display obvious junk?"*

Yes it does make sense: Spam is usually deleted within seconds, but you want to keep a record of a user's history. Same for abusive answers.

- > *"Could deleted answers not count towards the "self promotion" rule on bounties?"*

No, that'd make it too easy to circumvent the "self promotion" rule by deleting the answer, adding a bounty, then un-deleting the answer again.

Comment: 1. Perhaps we are using a different version. I am using Stack Exchange Android App 1.0.85. There is no delete button for answers, only Share, Edit and (under More) Flag.
2. Fair enough. I am not a frequent user of the app.
3. I just mean self-deleted answers that have attracted no attention. Other junk can be kept.
4. Fine, but that does feel like punishing legitimate users because someone might have found a way to slightly game the system.

Comment: 1:  I'm using the iOS version. They may be different. 3: I see no reason to delete them. 4: If you know of a alternative that works, SE is always open for suggestions.

Comment: You're right, the only reason to delete them that I have found so far is that I'm unable to set a 50 rep bounty on my question just because I clicked the wrong button and deleted the answer seconds later. A very small problem, just thought I would mention it.